# What does an asterisk "*" mean in hexdump output?

Tags: linux, dd, hexdump

I print MBR with hexdump and I get the following output:

```
000001a0  67 60 6f 70 65 72 61 74  69 6e 67 60 73 79 73 74  |g`operating`syst|
000001b0  65 6d 00 40 00 63 7b da  c5 f5 61 68 00 40 00 40  |em.@.c{...ah.@.@|
000001c0  00 40 00 40 00 40 00 40  00 40 00 40 00 40 00 40  |.@.@.@.@.@.@.@.@|
*
000001f0  00 40 00 40 00 40 00 40  00 40 00 40 00 40 55 ea  |.@.@.@.@.@.@.@U.|
00000200
```

What does the astersik `*` mean in the output?

Comment: It's `dump` and it means `same as above`.

Comment: OK, wonderfull, I was guessing it, but just wanted be sure :) Can you put it as answer?

Comment: `*` can mean more than one line be careful.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

A line in the hexdump output consisting just a `*` means `same as the line above`. This is mentioned in the hexdump's manpage at the `-v` option (easy to be overlooked).

Comment: Thanks!  That was super important for my parser to take into account!

Comment: @BuvinJ (or rather anyone else): You can just pass `-v` to avoid this, so that your parser doesn't need to take it into account.

Comment: `*` can mean one line of more, as many as there are until the proper offset.

Comment: This is super confusing when it's actually the first and only thing that `hexdump` shows, but what it really means is you've got a file with nothing but zeros in it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, without to verbose option to hexdump, `-v`, the asterisk indicates "same as above". Most likely seen on empty files or parts thereof:

```
> hexdump -C -s 12 -n 32 test-data/blk00000.dat
0000000c  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
0000002c
```

Adding the option `-v` to hexdump gives the full result, which is especially useful, if the output is used as input to some other process:

```
> hexdump -v -C -s 12 -n 32 test-data/blk00000.dat
0000000c  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
0000001c  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
0000002c
```

(Answer added for completeness)