# Head on very large files

Tags: dd, head

I have 2 very big files (27G and 40G), which are output of `dd` command on a failing hard drive.
I wanted to compare the first bytes to see if the 27G bytes is the begining/substring of the 40G.

I wanted to use `head` command. Since these files are binary, I used `-c` argument:

```
# ls -ahl *.dd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40G May 17 20:16 mac.dd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27G May 18 09:47 mac2.dd
```

**Trying to get 1K of raw data:**

```
# head -c1K mac.dd
(returns nothing)
```

**Trying to get 1K with hexdump:**

```
# head -c1K mac.dd | hexdump
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
0000400
(end)
```

**Trying to get 10K with hexdump:**

```
# head -c10K mac.dd | hexdump
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
0002800
(end)
```

Although:

**Trying to get 100 bytes of raw data on /bin/ls:**

```
# head -c100 /bin/ls 
ELF>�H@@p�@8    @@@@@@�
```

**Trying to get 100 bytes of hex data on /bin/ls:**

```
# head -c100 /bin/ls | hexdump
0000000 457f 464c 0102 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000010 0002 003e 0001 0000 4880 0040 0000 0000
0000020 0040 0000 0000 0000 b670 0001 0000 0000
0000030 0000 0000 0040 0038 0009 0040 001c 001b
0000040 0006 0000 0005 0000 0040 0000 0000 0000
0000050 0040 0040 0000 0000 0040 0040 0000 0000
0000060 01f8 0000                              
0000064
```

The results on the mac2.dd are exactly the same, but it seems the output is not really what I'm expecting so I don't think this means the files start with the same data.
Head on binary `/bin/ls` is what I was expecting.

I don't understand this output of `dd` files. Can anyone explain this to me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI: `ddrescue` is heavily recommended for failing drives, since it intelligently seeks around failed reads to recover as much as possible. You would have avoided this manual comparison entirely. (Note: `ddrescue` is in the `gddrescue` package on Debian/Ubuntu systems. The older `dd_rescue` script is in the `ddrescue` package.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is in fact a file from `ddrescue`... Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Ah, that would explain the empty files (or parts of files) - that must be what was skipped due to read errors...

Comment: You've answered your question, but I just wanted to mention your "(returns nothing)" clearly actually returned lots of NULs which didn't display anything.

Comment: @MarkHurd Totally exact.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering myself.

I found out from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/494245/what-does-an-asterisk-mean-in-hexdump-output), that the "`*`" in hexdump means "same as previous line". Meaning that my whole `dd` file is filled with `\0` chars.

I can make it explicit with :

```
head -c1000 mac.dd | hexdump -v
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000020 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000030 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000040 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
[...]
```

Or in a shorter way :

```
# hexdump -v -n1000 mac.dd
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000020 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000030 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000040 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
[...]
```

So now, I know that the `dd` dump is filled of nothing.

Thanks for anyone who read my problem down to here.